# Merge rows with same id but different values into single row per id

Tags: mysql, opencart

I have a query that finds categories by product id. Note: Some products can have multiple categories. My current query returns the same ids for different categories

```sql
SELECT 
  oc_product.product_id, 
  oc_category_description.name 
FROM 
  oc_product 
  LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_category ON oc_product.product_id = oc_product_to_category.product_id 
  LEFT JOIN oc_category_description ON oc_product_to_category.category_id = oc_category_description.category_id;
```

Result:

| product_id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | storage |
| 100 | SSD |
| 100 | HDD |
| 200 | storage |
| 200 | SSD |
| 200 | HDD |

I would like to merge the rows with the same product_id and add each category_name as an extra column to the left.

Desired output:

| product_id | category_name | category_name 2 | category_name 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | storage | SSD | HDD |
| 200 | storage | SSD | HDD |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns of an SQL query must be fixed at the time the query is parsed. A query cannot append more columns as it discovers the data during execution.

You could use pivot-table techniques, but only if you know how many columns you need for the number of categories per product.

I suggest you fetch the results in rows as in your first example, and then write code in your client application to format it into columns.